# I want change var color in js. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, var

I want change var color to blue. Blue to red. and red to Green. Can you help me please? Thanks...

```
function ColorChange() {
        var color = green;
        if color == "green" {
        var color = blue;
        }
        else if color == blue {
        var color = red;
        }
        else {
        var color = green;
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, your syntax is wrong for starters. You need to wrap your `if` conditions with parentheses. Ex: `if (color == "green")` Second, you only need to write `var color` once. Every other time should just be something like `color = blue`. Finally, I don't think you've defined `green`, `blue`, or `red` anywhere so you probably want them as strings `"green"`, `"blue"`, `"red"`. Try opening your console (hit F12) and you'll see errors. Then you can use `console.log(color)` to make sure it's changed to the right color.

Comment: Very confused as to what you're trying to do? If you set `color` to be *green* every time, it will never be *blue*...

Comment: Start with at least a basic javascript tutorial.

Comment: If you are trying to check if something has a text value of say red you will have to wrap the word in either single or double quotes. If you done have that then JavaScript thinks it is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ColorChange(color) {
    if (color == "green") {
        color = "blue";
    }
    else if (color == "blue") {
       color = "red";
    }
    else {
       color = "green";
    }
return color;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have *many* syntax errors in your code. Consider the following revisions:

```
function ColorChange() {
    var color = "green";
    if(color == "green"){
        color = "blue";
    }
    else if(color == "blue"){
        color = "red";
    }
    else{
        color = "green";
    }
}
```

Also, if you manually set `var color = "green";` then if your `if` blocks, none of them will *ever* return `true`. If you're trying to change a global variable whenever this function is called based on its value, it might look something like this:

```
var color = "green";

...

function ColorChange() {
    if(color == "green"){
        color = "blue";
    }
    else if(color == "blue"){
        color = "red";
    }
    else{
        color = "green";
    }
}
```

If you want this function to take in a `string` of color and return the permuted result, consider something like this:

```
function ColorChange(color) {
    if(color == "green"){
        color = "blue";
    }
    else if(color == "blue"){
        color = "red";
    }
    else{
        color = "green";
    }
    return color;
}
```

Overall, it seems you may be new to JavaScript and you might want to consider a [beginner tutorial to get familiar with the syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)

Comment: Good answer, but I'd introduce people to `===` early and pretend `==` doesn't exist.